# Python urllib POST response

Tags: python, post, urllib

I am trying to write script that searches an inchikey (ex: OBSSCZVQJAGPOE-KMKNQKDISA-N) to get a chemical structure from this website:
http://www.chemspider.com/inchi-resolver/Resolver.aspx

From the documentation my code looks like it should work, but instead it just returns the original search page.

Thanks for the help,

```
import urllib

inchi = 'OBSSCZVQJAGPOE-KMKNQKDISA-N'

url = 'http://www.chemspider.com/inchi-resolver/Resolver.aspx'

data = urllib.urlencode({'"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox1"':inchi})

response = urllib.urlopen(url, data)

print response.read()
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is performing a GET request and not a POST request. Apart from that: the form contains various hidden fields with some strange values which might be necessary for the processing as well.

Comment: What he said. Additionally, to avoid doing all the work yourself, you could use Mechanize (http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).

Comment: By default if you pass data to `urlopen()` it will perform a `POST` vs a `GET`.  The real issue is the missing hidden fields.